# Why running iTerm2 the first time installs pip3?

Tags: iterm2, pip

When iTerm2 is run for the first time on a Mac, it starts installing pip3. I am trying to understand why.

In my case I was on a slow network and the install would have take 3 hours, so I stopped the install. In spite of this, iTerm2 seems to be running just fine.

So what is the relationship between iTerm2 and pip3 and is the pip3 installation really required?

Comment: iTerm2 apparently has a [scripting API which uses Python](https://iterm2.com/python-api/) (so you can `import iterm2` in Python scripts to access iTerm2). Whether `pip3` is "required" isn't clear to me, but it seems out of the ordinary that an ~1.6MB file would take 3 hours to download (in contrast, iTerm2 is ~31MB).

Comment: It seems that the 3+hour installation time is for the Command Line Developer Tools, which is required for pip3.

Comment: I'm also wondering because I don't have Command Line Developer Tools when I start iTerm2 for the first time, the script cannot be installed. And after I install the Command Line Developer Tools and start iTerm2 again, if iTerm2 will try to install the script again?